# What does `?` mean after a set in nix language?

Tags: nix

What does the `?` in the last line means and why does this evaluates to `true`?

```
let
  attr = {a="a"; b = 1; c = true;};
in
  ex7 = ! attr ? a == false;
```

I've also tried

```
{a="a"; b = 1; c = true;} ? false
```

also evaluate to true, but

```
! {a="a"; b = 1; c = true;} ? a==true

! {a="a"; b = 1; c = true;} ? a==1
```

both evaluate to false.

Comment: See also: [What does `!a ? b` mean in a Nix expression? (i.e., Boolean negation of an attribute set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322379/what-does-a-b-mean-in-a-nix-expression-i-e-boolean-negation-of-an-attri)

Answer (score 3):

I've found it in the manual of nix language https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-language-operators .

> Test whether set e contains the attribute denoted by attrpath; return
>   true or false.