# What does `!a ? b` mean in a Nix expression? (i.e., Boolean negation of an attribute set)

Tags: nix

The snippet below got me confused because I know that the question mark in the function head is to supply default values, but in the `if` block it seems as if Boolean negation is attempted on an attribute set. This is not possible therefore I presume that I'm misreading this expression.

```
{ a ? null
, b ? 27
, ... }@args:

if !args ? a then
  # ...
else
  # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`!a ? b` is equivalent to `!(a ? b)`. To break it down:

```
nix-repl> a = { b = "0118 999 881 999 119 725...3"; } 

nix-repl> a ? b       # Does the `a` attribute set have
true                  # have an attribute named `b`?

nix-repl> !(a ? b)    # Negate the above results
false

nix-repl> !a ? b      # `?`  operator  has  higher
false                 # precedence then `!`, hence
                      # the parens can be omitted
```

The relevant [Nix expression language operators](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#table-operators) in the `if` block:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------------------------+------------+
|Name          | Syntax        | Description                    | Precedence |
+--------------+---------------+--------------------------------+------------+
|Has Attribute | e ? attrpath  | Test whether set e contains    |            |
|              |               | attribute denoted by attrpath; |  4         |
|              |               | return true or false.          |            |
+--------------+---------------+--------------------------------+------------+
|Not           | ! e           | Boolean negation.              |  8         |
+--------------+---------------+--------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: It does look odd. Redundant parentheses can make such expressions easier to read, because there's no standard for such operators beyond the language itself. (But generally not worth the effort of a review cycle to introduce them)

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the edit! I totally botched the answer with that one character omission...